# how do i write every character of a large txt file using python?

Tags: python, raspberry-pi

I'm trying to make a program to send every character of a text file through whatsapp web but, the file, is to large so when the program is making a large string it crash due to memory error.

Here is my code:

```
from pynput.keyboard import Key, Controller
import time
import random
pi = open('pi.txt').read()
keyboard = Controller()
input("Press enter to continue")
cont = 5
while cont > 0 :
    time.sleep(1)
    print(cont)
    cont -= 1

for x in pi:
    tic = random.randint(0,10)/10
    time.sleep(tic)
    keyboard.type(x)
    keyboard.press(Key.enter)
    keyboard.release(Key.enter)
```

random time is for whatsapp not to detect me as a bot

EDIT: The txt file is a single line so reading line by line will crash de program anyways

Comment: Do you have a specific question? Please see [ask], [help/on-topic].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was to split the txt file and its respective line into chunks so in that way the program will read it part by part instead of the whole file. By doing this, the entire file does not exist in the program at the same time.

Here is the resulting code:

```
from pynput.keyboard import Key, Controller
import time
import random
keyboard = Controller()
input("Press enter to continue")
cont = 5
while cont > 0 :
    time.sleep(1)
    print(cont)
    cont -= 1

chunksize = 1000000
with open('pi.txt', 'r') as f:
    while True:
        pi = f.read(chunksize)
        if not pi:
            break # done
        for x in pi:
            tic = random.randint(0,10)/10
            time.sleep(tic)
            keyboard.type(x)
            keyboard.press(Key.enter)
            keyboard.release(Key.enter)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try using the following code:

```
from pynput.keyboard import Key, Controller
import time
import random
keyboard = Controller()
input("Press enter to continue")
cont = 5
while cont > 0 :
    time.sleep(1)
    print(cont)
    cont -= 1

with open('pi.txt') as pi:

    for x in pi:
        tic = random.randint(0,10)/10
        time.sleep(tic)
        keyboard.type(x)
        keyboard.press(Key.enter)
        keyboard.release(Key.enter)
```

***Explanation:***
When you're using "**read**" method you actually read all the text in the file into the pi variable.

In the code above you can see that the iterations are made in a line-by-line approach.

Internally file are iterated lazily in chunks, so the whole file never exists fully in memory therefore not causing a crash.

Comment: The txt file is a single line because is the pi number so it crashes anyways. Thank you very much for answering.

Comment: @LKPaska _The txt file is a single line because is the pi number so it crashes anyways._ How large is that single line, though?

Comment: @AMC the file has 1 billon digits of pi, that is to say, 10^9 digits of pi or 10^9 characters in one line

Answer (score -2):

Well, it actually depends upon the speed and storage capacity of your computer, and there is another fact that you can't actually send a file more than 64MB big through WhatsApp web.  If you send every character from a file through python, you can only enter 65,536 characters of text in WhatsApp, so make sure it is not more then that.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/211917/discussion-on-answer-by-sannan-how-do-i-write-every-character-of-a-large-txt-fil).